# Image still appears in google search results in spite it has been removed from original source

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, search-engine-indexing, search-results

I have reported an image to google for removal under "remove outdated content" and in search console it says "This content is no longer live on the website", however the image still appears in google image search results. Could you tell me how I can remove that, please ? I have tried all ways, but still the removed content appears in image search results. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will just have to be patient.

Comment: Is some time needed for this, so that robot.txt can walk it and remove ? Do I understand it correctly ?

Comment: Search engines are not real-time. It is not possible. The web is just too huge. It just plain takes time to get around to each site in turn even with priority.